# How can i add a method in a class from another class in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I've a doubt, how can we add a method in `ClassA` using `ClassB`.

For example I've following code:

```
public ClassA{
     method1(){}
     method2(){}
}
public ClassB{
   //Here i want add another method for `ClassA`
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: As currently written, I’m not quite sure what’s being asked or what’s trying to be achieved. Could you add a little more to help explain what you’re looking for? Either some more description or maybe what the end goal is? For example, why not just add the new method directly to ClassA? Or is an extension method (or something else) what you’re looking for?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. My intention is: There is a class namely ClassA and it has method1() and method2(). In another .cs file i've ClassB (They just give the class name ClassA but, not .cs file so i can't add a method in ClassA) Here i want to add a method method3() to ClassA using ClassB. So that i can  use method3() anywhere when ClassA referred by some other classes.

Comment: Impossible in general, [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) may be the nearest way and [Emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) can do this but more complex.

Comment: @Chanikya Ok, I think I understand.  This is possible, and I've added an answer that shows a way to do this.  You might consider editing your question to include some of the info in your comment (the fact that you cannot modify ClassA.cs is helpful to know)

Comment: In your first line of text you say: "create a method in ClassA" but in your code comment you say: "add another method for ClassA". Please fix one so that both are consistent, otherwise this is way too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).  The first line from the documentation says:

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type.

As you mention in your comment ("They just give the class name ClassA but, not .cs file so i can't add a method in ClassA"), it sounds like you don't have access to the source code for ClassA.  Using an extension method, you can make your own method that can be called for an instance of ClassA.

In the sample code below, `classA.method3();` is possible:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        classA.method3(); // call the extra ClassA method you wrote
    }
}

// This class is assumed to be somewhere that you cannot modify
public class ClassA
{
    public void method1() { }
    public void method2() { }
}

// This is "ClassB" from your question, but I've renamed it to "ExtensionMethods"
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void method3(this ClassA classA) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what exactly you want, but inheritance is a solution:

```
public ClassB {
     public method3() {};
}
public ClassA : ClassB { // now ClassA has method3 too
     method1(){}
     method2(){}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not exposed"? OP says: "Here i want add another method for `ClassA`". Now ClassA has method3. What's wrong?

Comment: Why is the answer downvoted? Is something wrong with it?

Comment: If you can modify `ClassA` to make it inherit from `ClassB`, why not just add the method to `ClassA` in the first place?